# Print full name with \citet{} in natbib

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing, natbib

I use `\citet{}` in `natbib`. The problem is that it prints only the last name, but I also need the first name.

Are there any commands to print the full name?

## Edit

What I mean is that I sometimes start a sentence with

> Elon Musk states that [...]

and I imagine it to be better to write

> Elon Musk (2016, p. 8) states that [...]

rather than

> Elon Musk states that [...] (Musk 2016, p. 8)

But if I use `citet[p. 8]{musk2016}`, I only get

> Musk (2016, p. 8) states that [...]

instead of

> Elon Musk (2016, p. 8) states that [...]

Maybe I am all wrong about how to cite, but isn't this what the `\citet{}` command is used for?

Comment: Please given an example of a "full name". Any old name, or something unusual? Assuming the full name has first and last name components, should the first name or the last name be shown first?

Comment: Names are very tricky and you're not giving much information. With traditional BibTeX, see if the `usebib` package suits your needs; or switch to `biblatex` which offers more out of the box and is, in general, easier to extend.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

You could just write

```
Elon \citet[p.~8]{musk:2016} states that \dots
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{musk:2016,author="Elon Musk",year=2016,title="Thoughts"}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a suitable bib style

\begin{document}
Elon \citet[p.~8]{musk:2016} states that \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```